# Use Environ("LOCALAPPDATA") with a Public Const. (or an alternative solution)

Tags: excel, vba, constants

I have been using the following VBA code

```
Public Const COSTER_FOLDER = "C:\Coster"
```

But this will no longer work when they shift the folder location.

The new Coster folder is Environ("LOCALAPPDATA") & "\Coster"

Is there a simple way to do this using a Constant or is there a better way?

Regards Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another option. Remove the old definition, and use this.

```
Public Function COSTER_FOLDER() As String
    COSTER_FOLDER = Environ("LOCALAPPDATA") & "\Coster"
End Function
```

Then you can use it the same way:

```
Debug.Print COSTER_FOLDER & "\test.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks braX,  A nice solution that works perfectly.